# Quotient of derivative and function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\phi,\psi\in\mathcal{H}(D_1(0))$ be holomorphic on the unit disk about zero. None of these functions vanishes anywhere on this disk. I want to show that if,

$(\phi'/\phi)(1/n)=(\psi'/\psi)(1/n),\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash \{0\}$

$\phi=c\psi,\ c\in\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ follows.

I am stuck pretty early on this one, I could only figure out that by the identity theorem and since $0$ is a limit point, these two sides must equal everywhere on this disk.

Then since these function do not vanish anywhere I have $\phi'\psi=\psi'\phi$ on the disk.

I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: $\phi'\psi -\phi \psi'=(\phi/\psi)'\,\psi^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It folloes from the identity theorem that $\frac{\phi'}\phi=\frac{\psi'}\psi$. Now, consider the function $\frac\phi\psi$. Its derivative is$$\frac{\phi'\psi-\phi\psi'}{\psi^2}=\frac\phi\psi\left(\frac{\phi'}\phi-\frac{\psi'}\psi\right)=0,$$and therefore $\frac\phi\psi$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\left(\frac{\psi}{\phi}\right)' = \frac{\phi \psi' - \psi \phi'}{\phi^2}$$